# Como fazer um loop com jquery sem duplicatas

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, each

Queria saber se tem como fazer um loop dentro do outro usando a função `each` sem duplicar os valores

Exemplo

```
var cor = ["branco", "preto"];
var exa = ["#FFF" ,"#000"];


$.each(cor, function(index, values){
    $.each(exa, function(index1, values1){
        console.log(values + values1);
    }); 
});
```

***toda vez que executo esse exemplo o resultado sai assim:***

```
branco#FFF
branco#000 
preto#FFF 
preto#000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, só precisa fazer um vez, e pegar o indice para trazer o dado para segunda.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var cor = ["branco", "preto"];
var exa = ["#FFF" ,"#000"];


$.each(cor, function(index, value){
    console.log(value + " " + exa[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente!